# What does it implies to disable syscall in Intel SGX

Tags: kernel, intel, system-calls

I'm looking into programming with `Intel Software Guard Extensions (SGX)` facility recently. The idea of SGX is to create an enclave in which security-sensitive code is loaded and executed. Most importantly memory access (and many other restrictions) to that enclave is enforced by hardware.

In its [manual](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoftware.intel.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fmanaged%2F48%2F88%2F329298-002.pdf&ei=jXnCVLLEKfj9sASSgYG4Bg&usg=AFQjCNFzMoupt1zfDpqqWfX9nHASCihYfg&sig2=8Qh8tksPVxuJOJN3d6W7Fw&bvm=bv.84349003,d.cWc), I found that `syscall` instruction is illegal inside an enclave (see Table 3-1), along with many other instructions could possibly change privilege level. I wonder what does this imply. Since kernel service like `open`, `socket` end up in raising system calls, does it mean that banning `syscall` instruction actually prohibits code inside the enclave from any kernel service, like file and sockets? It sounds quite unconvincing to me because in that way what an enclave can do would be severely limited. So I think either I misunderstood or there are some work around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right when you say you cannot use kernel services or any system call for that matter because Syscall instruction is prohibited inside the enclave. 
The OS is not a part of the trusted computing base(TCB) in SGX. 
lets assume that syscall was enabled inside the enclave and you write instructions in assembly to execute the syscall instruction(lets say with parameters for the open system call sys_open). When you do a syscall you jump to the predefined location setup by the kernel during boot to start executing kernel code. What this means is you are jumping from code written by you(which is trusted) to code which is not written by you(OS, which is untrusted and is not a part of your TCB). If you were able to do this, it would defeat the security guarantees provided by SGX. Since the kernel/OS/any other software not written by you is untrusted, you could have a malicious kernel whose open system call reads data inside your enclave and steal your secrets.

This is severely limiting as you say because you wouldnt be able to use sockets or anything directly from inside your enclave code. But if you wanted to use these services inside the enclave, you have to trust code not written by you which breaks the security model of SGX.

I dont think SGX is intended for uses like what you may be thinking. here are some intended use cases as shown by intel and should explain how you can achieve these applications without the use of system calls.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-innovative-instructions-to-create-trustworthy-software-solutions

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Yes, what you said makes a lot of sense and system call should be banned. But I got some followup questions. 1) In the paper you pointed to, it's often mentioned that we have a *trusted channel* between enclave and remote server. But if `socket` stuff is not allowed, how does an enclave communicate with the remote server? 2) How does an enclave communicate with local enclaves? The manual said one need to pass `REPORT` to another in order to attest, but how is this done without system's help?

Comment: Or generally speaking, how do enclaves IPC without the help of system's help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems clear to me now.. So called *trusted path* is established on top of *untrusted path* offered by OS (traditional IPC between applications), with cryptographic protection (keys are only known to enclaves).

Answer (score 2):

Right. See local attestation in one of the three papers published by Intel on SGX. The enclave that wants to prove that it is running inside an enclave on an Intel CPU, creates a report inside the enclave(EREPORT). The report does not have any secret in it, but it is MAC'd using the report key, which is accessible and generated inside the enclave . The report is sent to the other enclave through the untrusted channel(Ie, OS provided IPC), and then the report is verified inside the other enclave, which has access to the same report key(shared secret) inside the enclave and can verify the structure integrity using the MAC and report key(shared secret between enclaves). If all the information in the report matches, the two enclaves can trust that they run on the same SGX platform. They can then perform key exchange like DH key exchange or any other way to establish a secure channel and they can communicate with each other securely.

Comment: I still dont get how enclave1 can transfer the report to enclave2. The report resides in enclave1. From there you could use EEXIT and return a pointer back to the application in untrusted space. The pointer cant be accessed as it points to Enclave. Sending from enclave1 to enclave2 directly is also not possible. Can you explain that part in detail?

Comment: the report that resides in enclave1 is first copied to untrusted memory of enclave1s process by the enclave itself. Remember the enclave can access all of the processes memory that is mapped. This is okay because the report does not have any secret. untrusted code then can use ipc provided by all operating systems to transfer the report to enclave2s process which is also untrusted memory. Then un trusted code in process two can call into enclave 2 which can then copy the report from untrusted memory of enclave2 s process into enclave 2s memory.